# Using event in jQuery custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameter-passing

I'm making a popup system and I'm having some issues with using `event` as an attribute in my custom function. Here is my code:

```
var openLayoutPopup = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(event.target);
    var flexible_field = target.closest('.acf-field-flexible-content').attr('data-key');
    var popup = $('.'+flexible_field);
    var overlay = $('.bbh-popup-overlay');

    popup.addClass('open').fadeIn();
    overlay.fadeIn();

}

$('.my-class').click(openLayoutPopup(event));
```

But my console gives me the following error saying event isn't defined:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

I've used `event.target` before and `event.which`, but only for unnamed functions.

Additionally, I have another similar function, in which I need to pass `event` and a secondary boolean parameter:

```
function closeLayoutPopup(event, openLayout){
    event.preventDefault();

    var popup = $(event.target).closest('.bbh-popup');
    var overlay = $('.bbh-popup-overlay');

    popup.removeClass('open').fadeOut();
    overlay.fadeOut();
    if(open == true){
        var dataLayout = target.attr('data-layout');

        acf.fields.flexible_content.add(dataLayout);
    }
}
```

Similarly I'm confused about how to pass the parameters in that one.

**EDIT:**

What I was trying to do explained shortly is having a button open a popup. Popup has two buttons, one to close popup and one to add layout to page and close afterwards. Issue was me calling functions wrong, and not realizing my solution was illogical.

I fixed the click events thanks to @Raibaz. Then I added to `closeLayoutPopup` to the `addLayout` function instead of combining them:

```
/*==============================================
=            Function - Close popup            =
==============================================*/
function closeLayoutPopup(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var popup = $(event.target).closest('.bbh-popup');
    var overlay = $('.bbh-popup-overlay');

    popup.removeClass('open').fadeOut();
    overlay.fadeOut();
}

/*=============================================
=            Function - Open popup            =
=============================================*/
var openLayoutPopup = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(event.target);
    var flexible_field = target.closest('.acf-field-flexible-content').attr('data-key');
    var popup = $('.'+flexible_field);
    var overlay = $('.bbh-popup-overlay');

    popup.addClass('open').fadeIn();
    overlay.fadeIn();

}

/*=============================================
=            Function - Add Layout            =
=============================================*/
var addLayout = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(event.target);
    var dataLayout = target.attr('data-layout');                

    acf.fields.flexible_content.add(dataLayout);
    closeLayoutPopup();
}

/*----------  add section click - open popup  ----------*/
$('.acf-field-flexible-content .acf-flexible-content > .acf-actions a.acf-button').on('click',openLayoutPopup);     

/*----------  Close button click  ----------*/
$('.layout-picker-close').on('click', closeLayoutPopup);

/*----------  Add layout  ----------*/
$('.bbh-popup a.add-layout-button').on('click', addLayout);
```

Comment: what is this?  $('.my-class(openLayoutPopup(event));   typo???  I'm not sure what you're intending there.

Comment: @Kosch Yeah that was typo of the year. I was deleting a really long selector and went a bit triggerhappy with the backspace button. It's back to normal now.

@t.niese if I pass `event` as a parameter on the click event for `'.my-class'` I get the error for that line. If I don't pass anything I get the error in the first line of the function `event.preventdefault()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to open the layout popup when clicking on elements with the `my-class` class, so your code should be something like this:

```
$('.my-class').on('click', openLayoutPopup);
```

The event parameter will be passed to the function when invoking the `openLayoutPopup` callback function.

You can have a look at the documentation for [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for reference.

As for the other function, instead of passing a second boolean parameter to the click event handler you could use a custom CSS class or a data attribute to indicate that there is an open popup, so your `openLayoutPopup` function could contain something like this:

```
$('body').addClass('has-popup')
```

and in your `closeLayoutPopup` you could just check if the class is present to determine if there is an open popup, and eventually remove it when closing the popup.

Comment: I feel like I tried your first example, but obviously I messed it up. Probably did it as `on('click', myFunction(event))`. But it works perfectly, thank you!
Regarding the other option I realize I have absolutely no need for the second parameter, as I can run the closePopup function from the function doing all the other stuff, which was what I was trying to differentiate. Closing the popup with an action or without an action.